# read_sql and Python handling "none" values

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, python-2.7

I am trying to write "Null" values to a Postgresql database using Python. This could be done by sending "None" values to the database. I have two versions of code. One is working and the other one is not.

How can I make pd.read_sql work with the below code?

```
data_w = None

sql = ("""insert into temp (field_1, field_2, field_3) values(%s, %s,%s)""") 

df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=db, params = (temp_id, temp_process, data_w))

Error: 
columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

However, the below code works.

```
cursor.execute(""" insert into temp (field_1, field_3) values (%s,%s)""", (temp_id, data_w))
```

I am a beginner, if you do not like the question then please "do not" downvote. Let me know and I will simply remove the post. I post here only after doing a sufficient search.

Best

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

The first case seems to be trying to iterate over the result of the execution, as if the SQL statement returned rows to go through. However, this is an `insert` statement that doesn't return any rows. Are you sure you need to use the function `pd.read_sql()` in this case?

The second case does not try to read anything from the execution result and works as expected.

Comment: I do not have to use pd.read_sql right not but it seemed like an important question to me. I thought community can benefit from it. I have used cursor.execute for now but in future, I might need the first one. Thanks for trying to help.